# IoT - KSQL Tumbling issues

Tags: apache-kafka, iot, ksqldb

Our JavaScript program writing 20 messages asynchronously using kafka-rest every seconds.
 We try to do aggregation on incoming message but it return some inconsistent result.

Please find topic, stream and aggregated result table definition below.

Topic:

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer –broker-list localhost:9092 –topic order_flow –property value.schema='{“type”:”record”,”name”:”myrecord”,”fields”:[{“name”:”OrderID”,”type”:”int”},{“name”:”OrderDate”,”type”:”long”},{“name”:”Status”,”type”:”string”},{“name”:”ProductID”,”type”:”int”}]}’
```

Stream:

```
CREATE STREAM ORDERS_SRC WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC=’order_flow’, VALUE_FORMAT=’AVRO’);
```

NEW STREAM – this stream use the actual event date rather than time when message wrote in kafka.

```
CREATE STREAM ORDERS WITH (TIMESTAMP =’ORDERDATE’) AS SELECT ORDERDATE,ORDERID, STATUS, PRODUCTID FROM ORDERS_SRC;
```

Now we are aggregating data based on it status using:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS_AGG_SEC as select Status,Count(*) from ORDERS_D WINDOW TUMBLING(SIZE 1 SECONDS) GROUP BY STATUS;
```

Now when we run query SELECT * FROM ORDERS_AGG_SEC; it returning below result

```
1522328177000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328177000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328178000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328178000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328179000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328179000 end=-} | Processing | 5
1522328179000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328179000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328180000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328180000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328181000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328181000 end=-} | Processing | 15
1522328181000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328181000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328182000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328182000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328183000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328183000 end=-} | Processing | 15
1522328183000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328183000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328184000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328184000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328185000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328185000 end=-} | Processing | 15
1522328185000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328185000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328186000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328186000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328187000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328187000 end=-} | Processing | 15
1522328187000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328187000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328188000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328188000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328189000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328189000 end=-} | Processing | 15
1522328189000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328189000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328190000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328190000 end=-} | Processing | 20
1522328191000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328191000 end=-} | Processing | 15
```

Expected Result:
I should get 20 count at every 1 second for Processing status

Actual Result:
I am getting more than one records for every 1 second interval for same status like below:

```
1522328179000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328179000 end=-} | Processing | 5
1522328179000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328179000 end=-} | Processing | 20
```

Please find my javascript code below:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max – min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
var orderdate = Date.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var data = {
        "OrderID": getRandomInt(1, 20000),
        "OrderDate": orderdate,
        "Status": "Processing",
        "ProductID": getRandomInt(1, 10)
    }
    node.send({payload:data}); // this function asynchronously call kafka-rest api producer.
}
```

Note: kafka rest api running with default properties

Answer (score 4):

KSQL uses Kafka Streams to run queries and the behavior you described is the one expected for aggregate results. Every time a new record arrives the query will execute and the updated results for the corresponding record will be emitted. You can configure how often the results are emitted by setting `commit.interval.ms` and `buffered.records.per.partition`.
The result you see in the output of your aggregate query indeed are the latest results up to that point. For instance

`1522328179000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328179000 end=-} | Processing | 5`

means that the count is 5 up to now (this is a partial result) and when you receive more records for the same group and window the count will be updated and a more up to date results will be emitted :

`1522328179000 | Processing : Window{start=1522328179000 end=-} | Processing | 20`

This means that the count is updated to 20 now.
If you want to have the most up to date results, you can materialize the results in a table. This way, the table will always have the most up to date counts for each group.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,   but how can i create a materialized view in KSQL ?  can you guide me and i did use setting  'buffered.records.per.partition' but in my case where every 100ms i am getting 20 records what is the ideal records per partition i should keep ?

Comment: The results of your query are written into a kafka topic. You can use Kafka Connect to materialize the topic in an external store such as a Key/Value store or a RDBMS. You can use JDBC sink connector for RDBMS systems such as mysql or postgres (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html) or Cassandra sink (https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-the-perfect-match/). The table in the RDBMS or Key/Value store will always have the latest result and only one value per key.